# /opt/local/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc: not found - Django Error

Tags: python, django, linux, less

Am running Django on Linux, using a django twitter bootstrap template. I have less css installed and can even access it from the command line. However, when I run the project, there is an error during template rendering at the this point:

```
{% compress css %}
```

with an error that the lessc module not found.

Could the path be wrong? The settings. py seems to be right.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should install `less` globally with:

```
npm install -g less
```

Also, I recomend you to consider similar django-app: [django-pipeline](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), because: [django-compress is no longer maintained](http://code.google.com/p/django-compress/).

With django-pipeline you can set a path to less compiler with `PIPELINE_LESS_BINARY` setting.